# Why is my var input null on the first run?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, redux-form, getelementbyid

I have an existing redux-form with Fields that I need to manipulate. I am adding css styles to the existing form before onSubmit using document.add.classList. With that I tell the form to add css-errors ('form-invalid', 'simple-form') after the first run, that much works. I need now to do the same with the Fields (inputs and label are using external css) but input is NULL on the first pass, so I cannot remove the class ('error') I need to remove before the input was even touched or focused. 
My goal is to get the fields to look "neutral" the first time they render. Like it is now they work fine, but show labels red from the beginning and makes not much sense for me to show errors before the user typed anything.

Is there any way to achieve what I need?

This is my component for redux-form Field:

```
renderField = ({
        input,
        id,
        name,
        customMobile,
        type,
        placeholder,
        meta: { error, dirty },
    }) =>
        customMobile ? (
            <div className="container_custom">
                <div className="group_custom">
                    <input
                        {...input}
                        id={id}
                        className={`custom_mobile ${error ? 'error' : null}`}
                        type={type}
                        onKeyDown={this._handleKeyDown}
                        onFocus={this._addErrorClassToForm(error, dirty, id)}
                        dirty={dirty.toString()}
                        required
                    />{' '}
                    <span className="highlight"></span>
                    <span className="bar"></span>
                    <label htmlFor={name} className="custom_mobile">
                        {placeholder}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        ) : (
            <input
                {...input}
                className={error ? 'error' : null}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                type={type}
            />
        )
```

This is the function I made to add and remove css calling classList (as mentioned, 'error' class in Fields is not being removed, because input is NULL at first pass:

```
_addErrorClassToForm = (error, dirty, id) => {
    var form = document.getElementById('form-abschluss')
    var input = document.getElementById(id)
    if (dirty) {
        if (error) {
            form.classList.add('form-invalid', 'simple-form')
            input.classList.add('error')
        } else if (!error) {
            form.classList.remove('form-invalid', 'simple-form')
            input.classList.remove('error')
        }
    } else {
        input.classList.remove('error')
        return
    }
}
```

And this is one of the Fields in the form:

```
 <Field
                            name="email"
                            id="email"
                            component={this.props.renderField}
                            type="email"
                            placeholder="E-Mail-Adresse"
                            onChange={this.props.addToCookie}
                            customMobile={true}
                        />
```

And here my css to show the new inputs behaviour:

```
input.custom_mobile {
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 20px 10px 4px 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px !important;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid #757575;
}

input.custom_mobile:focus {
    outline: none;
}

select.custom_mobile {
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 20px 10px 0px 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px !important;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid #757575;
}

select.custom_mobile:focus {
    outline: none;
}

/* LABEL ======================================= */
label.custom_mobile,
input.custom_mobile ~ label.custom_mobile {
    color: #696969;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 5px;
    top: 20px;
    transition: 0.2s ease all;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
}

/* active state */
input.custom_mobile:focus ~ label.custom_mobile,
input.custom_mobile:valid ~ label.custom_mobile {
    top: -10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: $cerulean;
}

input.custom_mobile.error ~ label.custom_mobile {
    top: -10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: $dark-pink;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 0 2px;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

I have been struggling quite a bit with this. Any help will be much appreciated!!

Comment: don't manipulate DOM like this, just use condition to set className of <input

Comment: Hi Tonoslav. I played around with classNames and worked too. Did not know that my first approach was a bad practice. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes it is required I this, for example when I wanted to set body class or something like this, page title etc, but in general if it is component generated by react, you should only manipulate it with props, becasue for example another render would erase/update classnames as they were defined in component by props

Answer (score 0):

Solved with pseudoclasses `input.custom_mobile.error:placeholder-shown`